# Difference between application insights application types

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm using application insights for my ASP.NET website. Recently I've added several web jobs and I found that there is an ability to configure app insights integration with them. webjobs SDK documentation is saying that I need to have my Application type set to "General" in App Insights: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Application-Insights-Integration. Currently it is set to 'ASP.NET'.
I have 2 questions here:

- What will be changed in my app insights after changing application type to 'General'. Could not google for anything related.
- Is there any way to change app type instead of recreating app insights instance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What will be changed in my app insights after changing application type to 'General'.

Application type affects what you see on the overview blade and the properties available in [metric explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-metrics-explorer). If you don't see your type of app, choose General. It means Azure will provide difference metrics for different application type. In addition, different application type need to accept the data sent by corresponding client SDK.

> Is there any way to change app type instead of recreating app insights instance?

I haven't found any way to do it on Azure portal. I also tried modify it using [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/Components/CreateOrUpdate). 200 OK is returned from Azure Server but the application type is not modified successfully.

Comment: Can I use General type for my Application Insights instance to capture insights from apps typed as Web App or App Service? Because I want to see insights from my functions app and web app under the same (single) Application Insights instance.